# React Native - Resize Drawer with Drag Handle

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-drawer

In React Native, is there any way to resize a Drawer with a resize handle by dragging the edge of the Drawer.  For example, like in the Slack screenshot here.  This is a very common use case but see no implementation of it anywhere online.

[image: Slack Example Screenshot]

I think it's possible with Pan Gestures but don't see a way to get a divider between the Drawer and Screen View.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks SugarFreeBeef, based on that I made a slight modification so it works by dragging a handle on the edge.  Here is a working example

```
import {Animated, PanResponder, StyleSheet, Text, View} from "react-native";
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {PanGestureHandler} from "react-native-gesture-handler";

export default function Page(state) {

  const [drawerWidth, setdrawerWidth] = useState(200)

  const panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
    onPanResponderMove: (_, { dx }) => {
      const newDrawerWidth = drawerWidth + dx;
      setdrawerWidth(newDrawerWidth);
    },
  });

  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={[ styles.drawer, { width: drawerWidth } ]}>
          <Text>Content of the resizable drawer</Text>
        </View>
        <PanGestureHandler>
          <Animated.View style={[ styles.drawerHandle ]} {...panResponder.panHandlers}>
          </Animated.View>
        </PanGestureHandler>
        <View style={styles.screen}>
          <Text>Content of Screen</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  drawer: {
    backgroundColor: '#F2F2F2',
    borderRightWidth: 1,
    borderRightColor: '#CCCCCC',
    zIndex: 1
  },
  drawerHandle: {
    height: 50,
    width: 10,
    marginTop: 100,
    marginLeft: -5,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    borderRightWidth: 1,
    borderRightColor: '#000',
    zIndex: 2,
    cursor: 'col-resize'
  },
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```